# Change navigation bar location

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I need to place the navigation bar at the top of the white view, but if I embed the view controller in a navigation controller it gets placed on the purple area, not on the white one. I know this approach is possible because I've seen it in some apps but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks[image]

Comment: You'll need to embed the white view controller inside a navigation view controller, then embed the navigation view controller inside the purple one. Check out this article: https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/

Answer (score 0):

Embed you navigation controller to the white view. Refer screenshot for clarification.
[image]